# Row containing minimum value of difference between two pandas columns - without groupby

Tags: pandas

In the sample data generated by...

```
np.random.seed(2020)
sz = 20
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(sz, 2), index=range(sz), columns=list('AB'))
df.insert(0, 'Item', 'X')
```

...to get the row containing the minimum value of difference this works correctly:

`df.iloc[df.groupby('Item').apply(lambda x: abs(x['A'] - x['B']).idxmin())]`

However, removing `groupby` using to get the corresponding `df.iloc`:

1. `df.apply(lambda x: abs(x.A - x.B).idxmin())` throws the error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'A'`
2. `df.apply(lambda x: abs(x['A']- x['B']).idxmin())` throws another error-type `KeyError: 'A'` !!!

Why is this happening?

What is the correct code to get the minimum value of difference, without using `groupby`?

Comment: Both `abs` and `apply` are not vectorized. You should just do `df.loc[(df.A - df.B).abs().idxmin()]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing the apply you have to supply the axis it should loop over. By default it will go column by column, hence the messages you are getting.

The following will work:
`df.apply(lambda x: abs(x['A']- x['B']), axis=1).idxmin()`

However, there is not need to use the lambda, you can do:
`abs(df['A']- df['B']).idxmin()`
or
`(df['A']- df['B']).abs().idxmin()`

Which both are also much faster than using apply.

Comment: Thx. Any idea why 1) and 2) gives different error codes?